# Vhost on nginx does not function as expected

Tags: nginx, centos, web-deployment, centos7, vhosts

My domain registrar's DNS hits my server and gets the nginx default page, so that's properly configured

I copied an nginx vhost that is currently working, changed the `server_name` and the name of the conf file and nothing else.

Diff:

```
diff 701sm.club.conf drz400.info.conf 
3c3
<   server_name www.701sm.club 701sm.club;
---
>   server_name www.drz400.info drz400.info;
```

then I restarted nginx.

Here is the entire non-functioning vhost:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.701sm.club 701sm.club;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/www/drz400.info/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/drz400.info/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        root /var/www/drz400.info/production;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /var/www/drz400.info/production;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Both sites should hit my `.../production/index.html`, but only one does. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Both sites should hit my .../production/index.html, for which url and why is php location present then(you can remove it if not needed)?

Comment: The DRZ url. PHP is present because I'm going to be running mediawiki.

Comment: are your php urls working properly?

Comment: only one hits index.html, then what does other do? and i see above that for the directory drz400, server name is 701sm this one.

Comment: the drz400 block hits my index.html as intended. I copied and pasted the block as a basis for a new site - 701sm - and only changed the server name line to test if it was being properly directed. It is not, instead, when you navigate to 701sm.club it hits my default nginx index.html, as in, the connection is not re-routed to a different root directory.

Comment: A friend went and looked at it and said that he hit my index.html when he used the full `www.701sm.club` but not the short `701sm.club` - I cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code,

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.701sm.club 701sm.club;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/www/drz400.info/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/drz400.info/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/drz400.info/production;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not fix my issue. I don't believe the problem exists within the server block anymore, I'm thinking it must be a larger config issue, since one of these sites works but the other doesn't with identical server blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Just got curious about your log directive, you point out the log to /var/www/drz400.info/logs/error.log while your domain was www.701sm.club. If you access www.701sm.club, is there any error on your error.log ?

And what type of error was occurred ?